# Issues in projection while defining data frame extent by coordinates

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

I'm trying to set the following coordinates to a dataframe:

```
custom_extent = {1:-87.678956, 2: -87.611652, 3:41.867129, 4:41.954932}
```

where `1` is key for `XMin`, `2` is key for `XMax`, `3` is key for `YMin`, and `4` is key for `YMax`

However, when I try to set the new extent up, the coordinates are not the results I expect. Here's a code snippet:

```
        print data_frame.extent.XMin                                        # prints 480718.855003
        original_spatial_reference = data_frame.spatialReference
        newExtent = data_frame.extent
        data_frame.spatialReference = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")
        print data_frame.extent.XMin                                        # prints -87.6986700746
        newExtent.XMin, newExtent.XMax = custom_extent[1], custom_extent[2]
        newExtent.YMin, newExtent.YMax = custom_extent[3], custom_extent[4]
        data_frame.extent = newExtent                                      
        print data_frame.extent.XMin                                        # prints -93.500018925
        data_frame.spatialReference = original_spatial_reference
        print data_frame.extent.XMin                                        # prints -2.38749449402
```

Every printout does not match the desired `XMin`: `-87.678956`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can't prove it, but I think the spatialreference of the newExtent is screwed up. Try setting the dataframe spatialref before copying the extent. That is, I think when you set the extent values, the software thinks it's still using the UTM or State Plane zone rather than WGS84. The values get unprojected again. Try checking YMin. If it is well south of where it should be...

Comment: I feel like I've done every rearrangement I can think of, and still to know avail. YMin generates the following printouts in order: 41.9085790737,
41.9085790737,
0.0,
0.0